# Python Bokeh MonthsTicker yields strange tick labels

Tags: python, datetime, plot, formatting, bokeh

I create figure with dates on the x axis as follows:

```py
plot = figure(
    frame_height=300,
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    x_range=(
        datetime(2018, 9, 1),
        datetime(2020, 6, 1)
    ),
    sizing_mode='stretch_width',
)

ds = models.ColumnDataSource(data.sort_values("date"))

plot.add_glyph(
   ds,
   models.Line(
       x="date",
       y="y",
   ),
)
```

The result looks as expected (see fig. 1). Now I want to format the xtick lables: Showing The month and year only on the first of each month:

```py
plot.xaxis.ticker = models.tickers.MonthsTicker(months=list(range(0, 13, 1)))
```

But now the xtick lables looks good in many cases, but in other cases it looks like in fig. 2. Any idea what could be wrong here?

I am using Python 3.10.4 and Bokeh 2.4.1 (newer version is not supported by streamline currently).

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Everything correct with the plots and the code, as @bigreddot mentioned in the comments, the formatting can be fixed with a suitable formatter. Adding the following x axis formatter helps:

```py
plot.xaxis.formatter = models.DatetimeTickFormatter(
    days=["%m - %Y"],
    months=["%m - %Y"],
)
```

Comment: That output looks correct. The purpose of a MonthsTicker is to put a tick on each and every month multiple (default 1 month) unconditionally. Maybe you want a different tick *formatter* if your are only trying to change appearance rather than location? Or maybe you want a higher months multiple? It's not clear what you actually want to have happen.

Comment: OH DAMN! Dealer several hours with this "issue" now and didn't realized that "5/01" means 1st of may and not May 2001! I used a formatter for formatting but set only the months scale. Uff my fault, thanks for helping!